# Intercept or trend in a VAR model for stationary percentage changes

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, trend, intercept

I am estimating a VAR model in R, using the `vars` package. There is an argument in `VAR()` function called `type=c("const", "trend", "both", "none")`, which is used to choose the type of deterministic regressor to include in the model. My question is, in which case should I use one or the other?

In my case, my variables are in percentage change and they are stationary, so I am using `type="none"`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You want the model specification that approximates the data generating process well enough. If your percentage changes have nonzero means (which is plausible in contexts with nonzero average growth), consider using `type="const"`, otherwise `type="none"` may be fine. (Presence of a linear trend in percentage changes would be unusual in most contexts that I can think of, so `type="trend"` and `type="both"` are unlikely to be a good fit; these would lead to overfitting.)